# How to start application on server from client app

Tags: c#, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have a client computer and a server computer (Raspberry Pi). the Pi has a MySQL database on it, and an application to read out RFID tags in a database. the app is written in C# and runs using Mono.

Now, I'm developing a C# application for the client computer which needs to trigger the startup of the application to read out tags.

How can I trigger that application's startup from my client computer by the press of a simple button?

What would be the most logical way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to return the RFID tags to the client computer?

Comment: The tags will be stored in the mysql database and indeed eventually be returned to the client application

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the RFID tags to be returned to the client application, then I suggest either:

1. Move the application to the client computer and connect to the MuSQL database on the server (PI) over the network.
2. Use WCF for inter-process communication between the client and server; WCF is supported by Mono: see here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/. The button press in the client application would call a WCF web method on the server PI. You will need a host process on the PI for your WCF service.